# I need to deseralize this json responce and get the attributes to display in pageblock table

Tags: json

```
{   "id": "LC-NCLDMHG",
    "created": "2018-06-12T18:59:00-07:00",
    "type": "longForm",
    "source": "Zillow",
    "price": 70,
    "sender": {
        "emailAddress": "testborrower@gmail.com",
        "firstName": "Anthony",
        "lastName": "Testborrower",
        "phoneNumber": "(206) 555-7472"
    },
    "details": {
        "annualIncome": 85000,
        "firstTimeBuyer": true,
        "hasAgent": false,
        "hasBankruptcy": false,
        "monthlyDebts": 0,
        "originalContactTime": "2018-06-12T13:31:11.163000+00:00",
        "propertyValue": 289000,
        "selfEmployed": false,
        "vaEligible": false,
        "creditScoreRange": "R_640_659",
        "downPayment": 8670,
        "loanAmount": 280330,
        "loanPurpose": "Purchase",
        "preferredLanguage": "English",
        "propertyType": "SingleFamilyHome",
        "propertyUse": "Primary",
        "stateAbbreviation": "CA",
        "city": "Modesto",
        "county": "Stanislaus",
        "zipCode": "95355",
        "loanToValuePercent": 97,
        "debtToIncomePercent": 0,
        "preferredContactTime": "2018-06-12T19:00:00-07:00"
    },
    "recipient": {
        "lenderId": "ZUyc2w36gf5wy1_6zfs8",
        "firstName": "Lender",
        "lastName": "Financial",
        "emailAddress": "test@lender.com",
        "phoneNumber": "(888) 826-2710",
        "nmlsLicense": "1124061"
    }   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Paste into https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/ and use the generated code.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this framework https://github.com/anyei/JPath-SFDC.

```
String senderEmail = (String) jpath.get('/sender/emailAddress');
```

Comment: Hi Elmer, Interesting link, but seeing this in the README "Code is ugly and not optimal and undocumented, need to improve it so that its better and faster" doesn't inspire confidence.